# PostgreSQL convert anyarray to array of type int

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I am trying to work with the `pg_stats` relation to learn more about how PostgreSQL does query evaluation.

I am trying to follow this page here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/row-estimation-examples.html to calculate some of the selectivity on my queries.

When working with the `histogram_bounds` as obtained from

```
SELECT histogram_bounds 
FROM pg_stats 
WHERE tablename='<table_name>' 
  AND attname='<att_name>';
```

where `att_name` here is an attribute of numerical type in the table `table_name`

The returned value is of type anyarray, even though (in my case) the attribute is an integer, so it's an anyarray full of integers. I have found very little documentation on this type, but it seems I can't use the simple cast conventions for getting it to a usable type. Apparently it does not support normal array options. I would like to cast this to an array of ints.

`histogram_bounds[0]`

> ERROR:  cannot subscript type anyarray because it is not an array

And cannot be cast

`CAST(histogram_bounds as int[])`

> ERROR:  cannot cast type anyarray to integer[]

Any help with how to cast this type to an int array would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hm, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-pseudo.html says "*A pseudo-type cannot be used as a column data type*", but [`pg_stats` doesn't seem to care](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-stats.html)

Comment: Try `histogram_bounds::text`? I have a feeling that always works. Maybe then cast that text to `int[]`

Comment: @Bergi Thank you! This is the answer - CAST(histogram_bounds::text AS int[]), or histogram_bounds::text::int[], works. If you answer the question I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can cast any type, even the `anyarray` one, to `text` for output. This text will have the integer array representation for a histogram of an integer column, so we can subsequently cast it to that:

```
SELECT histogram_bounds::text::int[]
FROM pg_stats
WHERE tablename='<table_name>'
  AND attname='<att_name>';
```